# JPanel with scrollbar set content not resizable

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jscrollpane

My goal is to display messages received with an UDP server in a box.
To do so, I've created a JScrollBar which I add a JPanel. 
When I receive a message, and object ReceivedCommand that extend JTextArea is created and add to the JPanel.
My problem here is that when I have too much messages displayed in the JPanel, it's automatically resizing my TextAreas.
How can I set the TextAreas not resizable so that the messages gets added even if they are not visible in the Panel and then make the scrollbar finally usefull.

Here is my test code to illustrate :

```
package test;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.ScrollPaneConstants;
import javax.swing.border.LineBorder;

public class test {

    public static void main(String args[]){
        JFrame frame  = new JFrame();

        JPanel RXCommand = new JPanel();
        RXCommand.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500, 250));
        RXCommand.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.black));
        RXCommand.setLayout(new GridLayout(0,1));

        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(RXCommand, ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED, ScrollPaneConstants.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
        scrollPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500, 250));

        RXCommand.add(new ReceivedCommand("11:02:56", "5", "5", "command exemple", "command exemple"));
        RXCommand.add(new ReceivedCommand("11:02:56", "5", "5", "command exemple", "command exemple"));
        RXCommand.add(new ReceivedCommand("11:02:56", "5", "5", "command exemple", "command exemple"));
        RXCommand.add(new ReceivedCommand("11:02:56", "5", "5", "command exemple", "command exemple"));
        RXCommand.add(new ReceivedCommand("11:02:56", "5", "5", "command exemple", "command exemple"));
        RXCommand.add(new ReceivedCommand("11:02:56", "5", "5", "command exemple", "command exemple"));
        RXCommand.add(new ReceivedCommand("11:02:56", "5", "5", "command exemple", "command exemple"));
        RXCommand.add(new ReceivedCommand("11:02:56", "5", "5", "command exemple", "command exemple"));
        RXCommand.add(new ReceivedCommand("11:02:56", "5", "5", "command exemple", "command exemple"));
        RXCommand.add(new ReceivedCommand("11:02:56", "5", "5", "command exemple", "command exemple"));
        RXCommand.add(new ReceivedCommand("11:02:56", "5", "5", "command exemple", "command exemple"));
        RXCommand.add(new ReceivedCommand("11:02:56", "5", "5", "command exemple", "command exemple"));
        RXCommand.add(new ReceivedCommand("11:02:56", "5", "5", "command exemple", "command exemple"));
        RXCommand.add(new ReceivedCommand("11:02:56", "5", "5", "command exemple", "command exemple"));
        RXCommand.add(new ReceivedCommand("11:02:56", "5", "5", "command exemple", "command exemple"));

        frame.add(scrollPane);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

ReceivedCommand :

```
package test;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;

import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.border.CompoundBorder;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import javax.swing.border.LineBorder;

public class ReceivedCommand extends JTextArea {
    public ReceivedCommand(String time, String init, String now, String cmd1, String cmd2) {
        this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(495, 50));
        this.setText("Reçu : " + time +" Canal initial : " + init + " Canal actuel : " + now + "\nCommande 1 :" + cmd1 + "\nCommande 2 : " + cmd2); 
        this.setBorder(new CompoundBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5), new LineBorder(Color.black)));   

    }
}
```

Comment: See [Should I avoid the use of set(Preferred|Maximum|Minimum)Size methods in Java Swing?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7229226/418556)  (Yes.)

Comment: I'm begening in swing, because my gui is meant to be implemented on a touch screen where I know the resolution, I haven't think about not using preferred method. Now that I've seen that this is kinda outcast from the good uses of development in swing, I'll try to not use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
JPanel RXCommand = new JPanel();
```

First of all, variable names should NOT start with an upper case character. The forum will highlight class names to make the code easy to read. Notice how the forum thinks your variable name is a class name? Learn and follow Java naming conventions.

> How can I set the TextAreas not resizable

```
RXCommand.setLayout(new GridLayout(0,1));
```

Don't use a GridLayout. GridLayout will take up all the space available. So the first component takes up 100% of the space. When you have two, each takes up 50%.

Instead use a `BoxLayout` or a `GridBagLayout`.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Layout Managers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) for more information and examples to get you started.

> and then make the scrollbar finally usefull

Already answered by Andrew's comment above.

Comment: Ok, I'll try to implement another layout tomorrow. I'll keep you informed

Comment: I've tried to use a BoxLayout and it seams to work fine but my scroll bar is not working. I assume that the problem comes from the `scrollPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500, 250));`. I tried to get rid of it but when I do so, the scrollbar disepears. What should I do to fix this issue ??

Comment: EDIT : I've found, this is the preferredSize of RXCommand that I have to get rid of .